# index-*.wt: encountered an illegal file format or internal - WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic - aborting after fassert() failure

Tags: mongodb, corruption, startup, trace, mongodb-3.2

One hypervisor went down for 7 seconds and afterwords I couldn't start mongod. See error. Replicaset with 3 nodes. I use `/var/lib/mongodb-mms-automation/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.2.8/bin/mongod`. I fixed the problem with deleting /data (re sync). Would there be an other fix? What is this error exactly saying? What wrong?

```
2016-08-10T20:01:13.307+0200 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] syncing from: xxxxxxxxxxxxx.domain
2016-08-10T20:01:13.326+0200 I REPL     [SyncSourceFeedback] setting syncSourceFeedback to xxxxxxxxxxxxx.domain
2016-08-10T20:01:13.344+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-BGSync-0] Successfully connected to xxxxxxxxxxxxx.domain
2016-08-10T20:01:13.350+0200 E STORAGE  [repl writer worker 0] WiredTiger (0) [1470852073:350754][18469:0x7fd349350700], file:index-5--7636776794640904198.wt, WT_CURSOR.insert: read checksum error for 16384B block at offset 410152960: block header checksum of 2720487603 doesn't match expected checksum of 334085110
2016-08-10T20:01:13.350+0200 E STORAGE  [repl writer worker 0] WiredTiger (0) [1470852073:350795][18469:0x7fd349350700], file:index-5--7636776794640904198.wt, WT_CURSOR.insert: index-5--7636776794640904198.wt: encountered an illegal file format or internal value
2016-08-10T20:01:13.350+0200 E STORAGE  [repl writer worker 0] WiredTiger (-31804) [1470852073:350806][18469:0x7fd349350700], file:index-5--7636776794640904198.wt, WT_CURSOR.insert: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2016-08-10T20:01:13.350+0200 I -        [repl writer worker 0] Fatal Assertion 28558
2016-08-10T20:01:13.350+0200 I -        [repl writer worker 0] 

***aborting after fassert() failure


2016-08-10T20:01:13.364+0200 I -        [WTJournalFlusher] Fatal Assertion 28559
2016-08-10T20:01:13.364+0200 I -        [WTJournalFlusher] 

***aborting after fassert() failure


2016-08-10T20:01:13.370+0200 F -        [repl writer worker 0] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

 0x131cfa2 0x131c0f9 0x131c902 0x7fd35a3aa100 0x7fd35a00f5f7 0x7fd35a010ce8 0x12a68a2 0x10a0a53 0x1a7e43c 0x1a7e8fd 0x1a7ece4 0x19b2f97 0x19cfcaa 0x19d5280 0x19f5727 0x19c36cf 0x1a11c9e 0x107d7ca 0x1081817 0xcb4b3f 0xb050b9 0xb0945f 0xb09500 0xae9215 0xae9581 0xae972b 0xebc731 0xf4e52e 0xf48370 0xf49fb6 0xf4abb6 0xf4de7b 0x12b0f21 0x12b1889 0x12b23e0 0x1b37960 0x7fd35a3a2dc5 0x7fd35a0d01cd
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"F1CFA2","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"400000","o":"F1C0F9"},{"b":"400000","o":"F1C902"},{"b":"7FD35A39B000","o":"F100"},{"b":"7FD359FDA000","o":"355F7","s":"gsignal"},{"b":"7FD359FDA000","o":"36CE8","s":"abort"},{"b":"400000","o":"EA68A2","s":"_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi"},{"b":"400000","o":"CA0A53"},{"b":"400000","o":"167E43C","s":"__wt_eventv"},{"b":"400000","o":"167E8FD","s":"__wt_err"},{"b":"400000","o":"167ECE4","s":"__wt_panic"},{"b":"400000","o":"15B2F97","s":"__wt_bm_read"},{"b":"400000","o":"15CFCAA","s":"__wt_bt_read"},{"b":"400000","o":"15D5280","s":"__wt_page_in_func"},{"b":"400000","o":"15F5727","s":"__wt_row_search"},{"b":"400000","o":"15C36CF","s":"__wt_btcur_insert"},{"b":"400000","o":"1611C9E"},{"b":"400000","o":"C7D7CA","s":"_ZN5mongo23WiredTigerIndexStandard7_insertEP11__wt_cursorRKNS_7BSONObjERKNS_8RecordIdEb"},{"b":"400000","o":"C81817","s":"_ZN5mongo15WiredTigerIndex6insertEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7BSONObjERKNS_8RecordIdEb"},{"b":"400000","o":"8B4B3F","s":"_ZN5mongo17IndexAccessMethod6insertEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7BSONObjERKNS_8RecordIdERKNS_19InsertDeleteOptionsEPl"},{"b":"400000","o":"7050B9","s":"_ZN5mongo12IndexCatalog21_indexFilteredRecordsEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_17IndexCatalogEntryERKSt6vectorINS_10BsonRecordESaIS6_EE"},{"b":"400000","o":"70945F","s":"_ZN5mongo12IndexCatalog13_indexRecordsEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_17IndexCatalogEntryERKSt6vectorINS_10BsonRecordESaIS6_EE"},{"b":"400000","o":"709500","s":"_ZN5mongo12IndexCatalog12indexRecordsEPNS_16OperationContextERKSt6vectorINS_10BsonRecordESaIS4_EE"},{"b":"400000","o":"6E9215","s":"_ZN5mongo10Collection16_insertDocumentsEPNS_16OperationContextEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKNS_7BSONObjESt6vectorIS5_SaIS5_EEEESB_b"},{"b":"400000","o":"6E9581","s":"_ZN5mongo10Collection15insertDocumentsEPNS_16OperationContextEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKNS_7BSONObjESt6vectorIS5_SaIS5_EEEESB_bb"},{"b":"400000","o":"6E972B","s":"_ZN5mongo10Collection14insertDocumentEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7BSONObjEbb"},{"b":"400000","o":"ABC731","s":"_ZN5mongo4repl21applyOperation_inlockEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_8DatabaseERKNS_7BSONObjEb"},{"b":"400000","o":"B4E52E","s":"_ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFN5mongo6StatusEPNS0_16OperationContextEPNS0_8DatabaseERKNS0_7BSONObjEbEPS9_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_dataS3_S5_S8_b"},{"b":"400000","o":"B48370"},{"b":"400000","o":"B49FB6","s":"_ZN5mongo4repl8SyncTail9syncApplyEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7BSONObjEbSt8functionIFNS_6StatusES3_PNS_8DatabaseES6_bEES7_IFS8_S3_S6_EES7_IFvvEE"},{"b":"400000","o":"B4ABB6","s":"_ZN5mongo4repl8SyncTail9syncApplyEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7BSONObjEb"},{"b":"400000","o":"B4DE7B","s":"_ZN5mongo4repl14multiSyncApplyERKSt6vectorINS_7BSONObjESaIS2_EEPNS0_8SyncTailE"},{"b":"400000","o":"EB0F21","s":"_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool10_doOneTaskEPSt11unique_lockISt5mutexE"},{"b":"400000","o":"EB1889","s":"_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool13_consumeTasksEv"},{"b":"400000","o":"EB23E0","s":"_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool17_workerThreadBodyEPS0_RKSs"},{"b":"400000","o":"1737960","s":"execute_native_thread_routine"},{"b":"7FD35A39B000","o":"7DC5"},{"b":"7FD359FDA000","o":"F61CD","s":"clone"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.2.8", "gitVersion" : "ed70e33130c977bda0024c125b56d159573dbaf0", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64", "version" : "#1 SMP Fri Apr 24 15:26:38 EDT 2015", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "5F3E5C743BB6FE5AA37A0C943A2741BC6F69AA7E" }, { "b" : "7FFF0FCFE000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B27B7E770B6D3351944DD8DF9D6966D998174435" }, { "b" : "7FD35B2C2000", "path" : "/lib64/libssl.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "0EB54305E0FF44D0CA1D792834387367E5DB17FB" }, { "b" : "7FD35AEDB000", "path" : "/lib64/libcrypto.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C4EC5A6FED7A243456EE5F14E5458C9DD0220B82" }, { "b" : "7FD35ACD3000", "path" : "/lib64/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A1D9E0B471D827008C36FA72BAB34BE08FE54B33" }, { "b" : "7FD35AACF000", "path" : "/lib64/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5958E57738366BCC217783F3CD4C836437F7C45F" }, { "b" : "7FD35A7CD000", "path" : "/lib64/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "02C4E38A8145201D9C574499CF75132551835CEB" }, { "b" : "7FD35A5B7000", "path" : "/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3D06B234BB28280F8B45C2A3B76DBFD9986FC7F5" }, { "b" : "7FD35A39B000", "path" : "/lib64/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "FA15B7D2CA650B34E6A0C9AD999BA6625AEC4068" }, { "b" : "7FD359FDA000", "path" : "/lib64/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B0A1DFA62C6AF7AA62487E3C260DC4B9C24D8BF8" }, { "b" : "7FD35B52F000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CEB78DAE1EE5B4C544047DC26F88A8E4586A34D2" }, { "b" : "7FD359D8E000", "path" : "/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "511A7F1757F2ABE2894651589D91269DAB895B86" }, { "b" : "7FD359AAB000", "path" : "/lib64/libkrb5.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "77B09D93C29E0D455D45790DE86303C07B003035" }, { "b" : "7FD3598A7000", "path" : "/lib64/libcom_err.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B25574847B066A26CD593C8101DF6779898FF2C2" }, { "b" : "7FD359675000", "path" : "/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6CD647AAA0631C7AF590B436DA74A6F373B5D6BB" }, { "b" : "7FD35945F000", "path" : "/lib64/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8934632E74819BCC23A16BD5659F1FFBB5243D93" }, { "b" : "7FD359250000", "path" : "/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "88AECC78BED1C6909C11C23C091DDDAC69BB1D30" }, { "b" : "7FD35904C000", "path" : "/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8CA73C16CFEB9A8B5660015B9223B09F87041CAD" }, { "b" : "7FD358E32000", "path" : "/lib64/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D08CF135D143704DA93E5F025AE6AE6943838F03" }, { "b" : "7FD358C0D000", "path" : "/lib64/libselinux.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5062031216B995004A297D555D834C0109F7598C" }, { "b" : "7FD3589AC000", "path" : "/lib64/libpcre.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "48073BD2BFFD1255A1AAB572CA1C3DC53AF5CD2A" }, { "b" : "7FD358787000", "path" : "/lib64/liblzma.so.5", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "218D03D1F6CF1A099A4D467B5E8ECF4F2BF45750" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x32) [0x131cfa2]
 mongod(+0xF1C0F9) [0x131c0f9]
 mongod(+0xF1C902) [0x131c902]
 libpthread.so.0(+0xF100) [0x7fd35a3aa100]
 libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37) [0x7fd35a00f5f7]
 libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7fd35a010ce8]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0x82) [0x12a68a2]
 mongod(+0xCA0A53) [0x10a0a53]
 mongod(__wt_eventv+0x42C) [0x1a7e43c]
 mongod(__wt_err+0x8D) [0x1a7e8fd]
 mongod(__wt_panic+0x24) [0x1a7ece4]
 mongod(__wt_bm_read+0x77) [0x19b2f97]
 mongod(__wt_bt_read+0x1EA) [0x19cfcaa]
 mongod(__wt_page_in_func+0x180) [0x19d5280]
 mongod(__wt_row_search+0x677) [0x19f5727]
 mongod(__wt_btcur_insert+0x45F) [0x19c36cf]
 mongod(+0x1611C9E) [0x1a11c9e]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo23WiredTigerIndexStandard7_insertEP11__wt_cursorRKNS_7BSONObjERKNS_8RecordIdEb+0x12A) [0x107d7ca]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15WiredTigerIndex6insertEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7BSONObjERKNS_8RecordIdEb+0xC7) [0x1081817]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17IndexAccessMethod6insertEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7BSONObjERKNS_8RecordIdERKNS_19InsertDeleteOptionsEPl+0x19F) [0xcb4b3f]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12IndexCatalog21_indexFilteredRecordsEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_17IndexCatalogEntryERKSt6vectorINS_10BsonRecordESaIS6_EE+0x109) [0xb050b9]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12IndexCatalog13_indexRecordsEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_17IndexCatalogEntryERKSt6vectorINS_10BsonRecordESaIS6_EE+0x11F) [0xb0945f]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12IndexCatalog12indexRecordsEPNS_16OperationContextERKSt6vectorINS_10BsonRecordESaIS4_EE+0x80) [0xb09500]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10Collection16_insertDocumentsEPNS_16OperationContextEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKNS_7BSONObjESt6vectorIS5_SaIS5_EEEESB_b+0x325) [0xae9215]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10Collection15insertDocumentsEPNS_16OperationContextEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKNS_7BSONObjESt6vectorIS5_SaIS5_EEEESB_bb+0x1B1) [0xae9581]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10Collection14insertDocumentEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7BSONObjEbb+0x6B) [0xae972b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl21applyOperation_inlockEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_8DatabaseERKNS_7BSONObjEb+0xF41) [0xebc731]
 mongod(_ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFN5mongo6StatusEPNS0_16OperationContextEPNS0_8DatabaseERKNS0_7BSONObjEbEPS9_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_dataS3_S5_S8_b+0x1E) [0xf4e52e]
 mongod(+0xB48370) [0xf48370]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl8SyncTail9syncApplyEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7BSONObjEbSt8functionIFNS_6StatusES3_PNS_8DatabaseES6_bEES7_IFS8_S3_S6_EES7_IFvvEE+0x336) [0xf49fb6]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl8SyncTail9syncApplyEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7BSONObjEb+0xE6) [0xf4abb6]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl14multiSyncApplyERKSt6vectorINS_7BSONObjESaIS2_EEPNS0_8SyncTailE+0x9B) [0xf4de7b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool10_doOneTaskEPSt11unique_lockISt5mutexE+0x121) [0x12b0f21]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool13_consumeTasksEv+0xA9) [0x12b1889]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool17_workerThreadBodyEPS0_RKSs+0x100) [0x12b23e0]
 mongod(execute_native_thread_routine+0x20) [0x1b37960]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x7DC5) [0x7fd35a3a2dc5]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7fd35a0d01cd]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

Answer (score 1):

mongo , as many other databases verifies that the files were written to disk as expected. 
In this case some writes have been lost and the checksum at the block header doesn't match the computed checksum on the block.

Hence the server failed to start. 
Note, it's a good thing as the other option would be to start the server with corruption.

Regards 
Jony